# Fixing the dashed style borders perfections

Tags: html, css, firefox, border

This is my code structure:

```css
.divider-line {
  height: 5px;
  border-top: 1px dashed red;
  border-bottom: 1px dashed red;
}
```

```html
<div class="divider-line"></div>
```

The left and right edge of the dashed border do not match in Firefox. How can I solve this issue? The same issue happens with a dotted border.

My output image:

[image]

Comment: If I run this code in Firefox, I only see 1px difference which is not much but yes it's noticeable. This happens even if you split it into 2 divs and apply top and bottom border separately. I wouldn't bother as it's only with Firefox. Is this breaking your design completely?

Comment: Thank you much.. its not breaking the complete design but it is noticeable so i would like to fix it.. can i achieve the same output using rather than border property?

Comment: Upon careful examination I saw that this is not the case. For top border it's keeping the left part as fixed and updating the border while for the bottom border, it's keeping the right part as fixed and updating the rest of the border so the left most part is appearing broken sometimes. Try changing the window width or zoom level and see the difference.

Comment: Thank you.. i have examined that what u said..!! I hope i can get some hacks to firefox..